# Fake path of input image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to take the input image from my device but I can't.

It's give me a default image that I gave, and return a fake path of input.

Can anyone solve it and give me suggestions?.
Thanks!

JavaScript:

```js
const [Image, setImage] = useState('')

    const fetchImage = async (e) => {

        // console.log('e is ',e)
        try {
            const response = await import('./img/noprofil.jpg')

            console.log('res is ', response)
            setImage(response.default)
            console.log("image in response is " + response)
        }
        catch (err) {

            console.log('error is ', err)
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```html
 <div className="col-3 ">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="img-holder">
      <img src={Image} className="rounded" alt="" />
    </div>
    <input type="file" accept="image" name="image-upload" id="input" onChange={fetchImage} />
    <div className="label">
      <label className="image-upload" htmlFor="input"> Change </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure about your use case. I made this general example of how to load local images in React. The image goes inside the public folder and you can access it directly inside the app. Here I create a simple codesandbox for better understanding.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-public-l03rc7